# Replacement for a Suntour Superbe front derailleur

Tags: road-bike, derailleur-front

I broke my front derailleur trying to adjust it. It's on a 1980's Klein Performance road bike.

Should I try getting only the same one, or is there any replacement that could work well in its stead?

I love the bike, and the metal looked cheap after breaking so I don't mind trying an upgrade.

TIA[image][image]

Comment: FDs are quite crude things, especially in the 80s. No great sophistication Two blades that force the chain from one ring to the other. If you find one that fits and works get it and install it. You'll have to check whether it is for braze-on or seat-tube clamping, double or triple chain-rings. Our LBS if it's established long enough might have some old new stock hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

Suntour Superbe parts were great, but they have been out of production for decades, and in any case, technology has marched on. Finding a direct replacement part might appeal to vintage enthusiasts, but there's no need to do so for functional reasons. New front derailleurs may have a slightly shorter maximum "throw" because chainrings are spaced closer these days. I don't know whether this would affect you, but I'm guessing not.

One quirk of the Klein is tubing diameters that were at the time considered oversize. As best as I can determine, Klein seat tubes had a "normal" diameter of 1¼", which is a good fit for the clamps on modern front derailleurs, but I would double-check that just to make sure.

Comment: I added 2 pictures, do they help narrow down the options?

Comment: I can't measure anything based on those photos. Take it to a bike shop.